# What is the grammatical function of 'with the aid of' in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Reading [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)#Types_of_objects), it seems to me that 'with the aid of' in the following sentence is a prepositional object. I suspect I may be wrong and would like a simple explanation about the grammatical functions of 'with the aid of' in the following sentence:

> With the aid of a physiotherapist, everything turned out fine.

- There's a similar thread [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137148/what-are-the-differences-in-meaning-among-aid-assist-help-and-facilita) but it doesn't address my question about grammatical functions.

Comment: It's a prepositional phrase used as an adverb. How everything turned out. It could go at the end too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminology of [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), *with the aid of a physiotherapist* is an [**adjunct**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)) (meaning, one can remove it and the sentence is still grammatical even when all the words in the remainder are taken in the vary same meanings they had before the removal). More precisely, it is an adjunct of **means** (as in, 'by what means' was something done). Other sources might call it an **adverbial** of manner. However it is called, it is realized by a preposition phrase (PP). The [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of this PP is the preposition *with*, and the complement of this preposition is the noun phrase (NP) *the aid of a physiotherapist*. The whole PP is **fronted**, though it could also be placed at the end, as in *Everything turned out fine with the aid of a physiotherapist*.

Note that *with the aid of* is actually not a [syntactical constituent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)) of the sentence. The constituent structure is, rather, this: *[With [the [aid [of [a physiotherapist] ] ]*. As I said above, the whole thing is a PP whose head is *with* and whose complement is the NP *the aid of a physiotherapist*. That NP, in turn, is composed of the determiner *the* and the nominal *aid of a physiotherapist*. The head of the nominal is the noun *aid*. The nominal also has a post-head complement, which is the PP *of a physiotherapist* (it is a complement rather than a modifier because the head noun **licences** the particular preposition; *aid* here cannot be followed by just any PP, but only by PPs headed by a very restricted set of prepositions, such as *of*. For example, *on* would not work at all, regardless of what followed it). Finally, this final PP has a complement, the NP *a physiotherapist*, which consisits of a determiner, the indefinite article, and the nominal, which is the noun *physiotherapist*.

Comment: It's adverbial, I'd say. But I guess that doesn't fit whatever grammar you use.

Comment: @Lambie Indeed, many sources would call it that: an **adverbial of manner**. I added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. You know when I read some of the explanations in terms of actual OP questions, they seem over the top. Much of the time, I doubt they will be understood by most participants here. Why do you feel it necessary to drill down as much? I don't mean not drill down at all, but is re-invention of the wheel called for? Just wondering...With the aid of an angel on the head of a pin....:)

Comment: @Lambie 1. Mostly because I learn that way, which is the main reason I'm answering anyway. 2. If they really don't understand, I hope they'll ask. 3. If they don't understand, they definitely don't need to accept. 4. My experience from the now-defunct Grammarly question-and-answer site is that a significant portion of askers do appreciate detailed answers. 5. There's a lot of people providing answers here, in all kinds of styles. It is good that this variety includes some who give in-depth answers that err on the side of being too detailed. Someone else can give pithy ones...

Comment: @linguistictum I was not suggesting not into details; I am suggesting that "learning languages" goes by chunks of utterances and going down to the atoms does not always help pedagogically. That's all. It would help one get one's Phd, though.  I don't mean to sound mean or anything. It is just how I see things, I guess.

Comment: @Lambie True... Probably I do overdo it.

Comment: And I probably under do it. :)

Comment: @Lambie So how would you modify the answer above, for example? So that it's still detailed but not over the top?

Comment: @Lambie Especially given this ELU SE is not oriented toward English learners, who really should be over on ELL. I probably overdo it there, too, but that's a bit different... (I didn't think you were mean for one second. In fact, I appreciate the openness and wish more people were like that: frank, but constructive!)

Comment: I would parse it at phrase level and  explain the function of the phrase as a  whole. Partly, the problem is the wrong parse by the OP. I would probably suggest: with the aide of [x] as a phrase. Well, to me usage is more stylistics...but not everyone would agree with that. I understand this is not ELL.

Comment: @Lambie OK. And if you wanted to explain that 'with the aid of' (which is in the title) is not really an appropriate word group to focus on (since it is not a constituent)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76528/discussion-between-lambie-and-linguisticturn).