# Help or Assistance? Are these interchangeable?

Tags: verbs, formality

In a work setting, which of the following is more acceptable to say in email messages?

> 1. Thanks for your *help*
> 2. Thanks for your *assistance*

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137148/what-are-the-differences-in-meaning-among-aid-assist-help-and-facilita

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), taking care to note the comments on search & research, including: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"